# `no such file or directory` with `os.Remove` inside go routine

Tags: go, go-cobra

I added a new command to my CLI application using the Cobra framework. This command is supposed to start a TCP server that accepts socket connections. It receives a payload which is an `absolute` path to a file/directory and tries to delete it. Here is the code for the command

```golang
package cmd

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    "wpgenius.io/util"
)

var cachePurgerCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "cache-purger",
    Short: "Listen for request to purge NGINX page cache",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        dstream, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9876")

        if err != nil {
            util.HandleError(err, "Can not start listener..")
            return
        }

        fmt.Println("Listening for purge requests...")

        defer dstream.Close()

        for {
            con, err := dstream.Accept()

            if err != nil {
                util.HandleError(err, "Can not accept connection")
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            go handleRequest(con)
        }
    },
}

func handleRequest(con net.Conn) {
    path, err := bufio.NewReader(con).ReadString('\n')

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    defer con.Close()

    err = os.Remove(path)

    if err != nil {
        con.Write([]byte("ERROR"))
        fmt.Println(err)
        util.HandleError(err, "Can not delete cache file")
        return
    }

    con.Write([]byte("SUCCESS"))
}

func init() {
    rootCmd.AddCommand(cachePurgerCmd)
}
```

Although the file/directory exists, I still get `no such file or directory` error.
I did a sanity check by simply adding the `os.Remove` to the `main` function to make sure it's not related to the path and I can see it successfully delete the file/directory.

I'm not sure if it has something to do with `go routing` or with the `tcp server`!

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: I trust the error message.  The file path you've provided to `os.Remove` is not right.  It might be relative and your current working directory doesn't match, or just wrong.  I wouldn't expect the TCP server to be implicated - make sure the file path is right.  I would consider moving a few layers up the OSI stack model and using something like HTTP for your server instead of direct TCP - http is a lot more opinionated about how to pass data ,and that will remove a bunch of decisions you'll have to make otherwise.

Comment: Thank you @DanielFarrell, I had the exact guess about the path as you, yet I verified the path multiple times plus, it works fine if I run `os. Remove` for the same input from the `main` function. I'm using TCP instead of HTTP because I had to disable the `HTTP` functionality in the application that requests this cli (due to security concerns), and the only way is to use sockets.

Comment: Okay! I figured it out! @DanielFarrell was right! I should have trusted the error message. The reason the path became invalid was the `\n` At the end of the input. By running it through `strings.TrimSpace` it became a valid path 

Comment: The lesson here is: print strings with `%q` when logging, so that you can see otherwise-invisible characters.

Comment: there is nothing inherently more secure about TCP vs HTTP, which uses TCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the point is \n in the path you input.